# Javascript optimization with `new Function()`

Tags: javascript, optimization, eval

While reading docs, I have found an simple optimization that greatly improves javascript performance.

Original code:

```
function parseRow(columns, parser) {
  var row = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    row[columns[i].name] = parser.readColumnValue();
  }
}
```

Optimized code :

```
var code = 'return {\n';
columns.forEach(function(column) {
  code += '"' + column.name + '":' + 'parser.readColumnValue(),\n';
});
code += '};\n';

var parseRow = new Function('columns', 'parser', code);
```

Found here : https://github.com/felixge/faster-than-c 
Why does it run 20% faster ?
I believe that it removes the `for` statement, but doesn't the `forEach` have the same computational cost ?

Comment: Is it talking about 20% gain with the function creation logic itself? Or with every call to the function parseRow? If it’s the latter case, I would assume the gain is happening because of the absence of for loop in optimized code. (In first case, for loop would run with every call to parseRow function. Also multiple calls to columns.length property could also be attributing to the slowness of the original code. Just my 2 cents :))

Comment: Related (for V8) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw

Comment: when size of `columns` is large enough, the 'optimized code' doesn't seem to be faster. see [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/javascript-optimization-with-new-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that you are only using `forEach` to **construct** the optimized function. Once the function is created, there isn't any looping inside: the [loop is unrolled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) and column names are [hardcoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding). The method is then `eval`ed into a working function, which might even be compiled into machine code, [depending on the engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)). This results in two performance improvements:

1. By removing the `for` loop condition check (`i < columns.length`) completely, there is no branching, and
2. By hardcoding values of `column[i].name` into multiple statements, you removed evaluating `column[i]` and lookups to `column.name` in each step.

So after calling `new Function(...)` with the code passed as a `String`, your `parseRow` variable gets the reference to the following function:

```
function parseRow(columns, parser) {
    return {
        "columnOne": parser.readColumnValue(),
        "columnTwo": parser.readColumnValue(),
        "columnThree": parser.readColumnValue(),
        ...
    };
}
```

Note that there aren't any loops, branching, or other lookups in that code, except for the multiple `parser.readColumnValue()` calls.

**Why is this possible in JavaScript?**

The reason why this works so efficiently in JavaScript is because JavaScript source code in any web page needs to be interpreted or compiled by the JS engine anyway. You don't ship your webpage with compiled executables, or even (somewhat) precompiled bytecode (like Java or .NET). Every single time a new `.js` file is loaded, your browser will compile it from scratch before running it (well, to be precise, in modern engines it's something between interpreting and compiling, i.e. [JITting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)).

This means that creating a working function from a string (i.e. compiling the code) during runtime is not any less efficient than having hand-written code being read from the .js file. Compare that to a C/C++ program, which is (in all reasonable cases) compiled to machine code (i.e. executable file which is as close to the CPU as you can get) [before it reaches the customer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation).

If you wanted to do this in C++ (a sort of a [self-modifying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code)), you would have to bundle a compiler along your app to build the code, and the cost of building this function would overweight the benefits you would get when you would finally start it. In .NET, for example, it is also not unusual for a program to [emit methods or even assemblies at run time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75(v=vs.110).aspx), which then get JIT compiled to machine code allowing potential performance improvements such as the one in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The performance gains depend a lot on the JavaScript engine, as well as on the data, that is being processed. We don't know the exact circumstances of "20% faster" (except for using node.js). It could be slower in some situations. (**Edit:** You would need to call the function often enough to outweigh the construction cost). Some possible reasons for the gains:

The optimized code creates an object literal. The previous version constantly assigns values to not yet existing properties. That has some cost associated with it.

`row[columns[i].name]` has three lookups, whereas the optimized version has none, once the function is constructed. And don't forget that `row[columns[i].name]` doesn't exist yet, so the lookup is more expensive. `columns.length` is a lookup, too.